# How to add SwingX palette in Window Builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swingx

I am using Windows Builder Pro in my Eclipse Helios. In NetBeans I know how to add SwingX palette. How can I add SwingX palette in Windows Builder?

Comment: swingx tag added to try to get kleopatra's attention.

Comment: @Hovercraft - thanks :-) Though, dont know the answer, never tried due to never using a builder not invented here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was playing around with it, and I have the solution.
SwingX ships in 2 jars- `swingx-all-1.6.3.jar` and `swingx-beaninfo-1.6.3.jar`, the second one contains `BeanInfo` classes. These are necessary if you want to import them as java beans in any IDE. So you need to merge them into a single library.

Here's what worked for me:

- Make a directory called `swingx`.
- Change to it, and unjar `swingx-all-1.6.3.jar`. Make a backup of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, say to `../backup.mf`.
- Unjar `swingx-beaninfo-1.6.3.jar` to the same location. Its manifest will overwrite the previous one, hence we needed to backup.
- Make sure you're in the same directory where you extracted the jars, and create a new jar that combines both of these, using the following commandline:
  `jar -cvfm swingx-combined.jar ../backup.mf *`

This will create a fresh jar that has both the manifest (which lists all java beans within the jar) and the required `BeanInfo` classes.

Import this jar into WindowBuilder and you'll be able to add the required SwingX beans from it.

Comment: how can i execute `jar -cvfm swingx-combined.jar ../backup.mf *` command on Windows XP. i tried with the command line but it says jar not a known command.

Comment: Make sure the `jar` command is on your path, or type `PATH=%PATH%;<path to jar.exe in your JRE/JDK>` before you type the above command.

Answer (score 5):

If you right click on an entry in the palette, you can open up the Palette Manager, then "Add Category", and "Add Entry" or "Import Jar".

Also, if you just add whatever component you want (ie: JXTable) using Custom, it'll automatically show up in a Custom category in your palette.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner solution is simply to add both `swingx-all-1.6.4.jar` and `swingx-beaninfo-1.6.4.jar` to your build path.

Then, in the palette manager, import the swingx-all-1.6.4.jar, selecting all items.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to add to the pallete. But, if you add the component in the source code it apears at the preview. Then you can drag it as if you got it from the pallete.

I hope it helps. Helped me...

Answer (score 0):

First of all download SwingX 1.6.4 All -sources and SwingX 1.6.4 BeanInfo -sources from https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads?search_tag=swingx-all-1.6.4.jar+&commit=search
and then add these jars to the elipse by going to project->properties->Add External JARs.